# ガウス・ジョルダン法等で3点の座標から二次関数を求めるSwiftのプログラムが作りたいです。

Tags: swift

二次関数を求めるにあたりまして、様々な方法があるとは思いますが、ネット上で見掛けましたガウス・ジョルダン法での3点の座標、(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)から二次関数を求めるSwiftのプログラムが作りたいと考えています。

y = ax^2 + bx + c

y1 = ax1^2 + bx1 + c ･･･(2)
y2 = ax2^2 + bx2 + c ･･･(3)
y3 = ax3^2 + bx3 + c ･･･(4)

(2)～(4)の式を行列を使い以下のように表す
|y1| |x1^2 x1 1| |a|
|y2|=|x2^2 x2 1| |b|
|y3| |x3^2 x3 1| |c|

変形させ

|？| |1 0 0| |a|
|？|=|0 1 0| |b|
|？| |0 0 1| |c|

a、b、cを求めるプログラムとしてどの様に記述するのが適切でしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 後は自分で決めた仕様と Swift の文法に従ってコードを書くだけのように思えますが、何が問題なのかを具体的に書いておくと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。行列を扱う場合、Swiftでは標準をあまり聞いた事がないのですが、これは自前で実装しなければならない感じなのでしょうか。

Comment: Rosetta Code に [Gaussian elimination](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Swift) があるので参考にしてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。見てみます。普段コードを書かないのでなかなか難しいです。